# How to set "local" for DateTime.ToLocalTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How does .NET determine where I am? How can I manipulate my current location and thus the behavior of this method?

The reason is I'm using .NET MF on a microcontroller board. Here I don't have any operating system. Still I want to convert times to my local time.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");//culture name
```

Comment: Like above: That does not work in .NET micro framework. "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture" does not exist. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways, you either set the CurrentCulture for your whole instance

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); //For German
```

or you can just use it to format your outputs like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d",new CultureInfo("de-DE"))); //For German
```

Comment: That does not work in .NET micro framework. "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture" does not exist.